# How erase the rest line from WGS84 projection?

Tags: qgis, line

I am working in world map (the Natural Earth data) which I would like to readjust for a political map of the world.

So, I have already changed the central meridian in Mercator projection, but I discover a new problem. It is a line which is the rest from orginal WGS84 projection that divide continental Russia and its island into two parts. The functions dissolve and split dont work. The line is still in the map :-(

[image]

Comment: Why does "dissolve" not work? Do you recieve any errormessage? You can also try "merge selected features" from advanced digitizing toolbar.

Comment: @ MrXsquared, because there is a gap between the polygons: -) ...

Comment: Dear Cyril,

Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I have tried the approch, but the last step produced an undesirable outcome. I sent you an e-mail.

Best wishes,
Mila

Comment: Míla, your question solves the difference of small buffers, tested on the geodata you provided (source - https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) using PostgreSQL / PostGIS ... Due to the fact that the accuracy of the geodata provided by the resource corresponds to 1:10 000 000, then this approach is applicable, with respect ...

Comment: Strange, for some reason, I do not see the correct answer to the specified link in the question (duplicate), although the answer is accepted?